# Show only Message from ApplicationException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I am trying to have an ApplicationException exception which will show ONLY a message when input is not a number. Here is what I have right now:

```
static void getBookInfo(Book book)
{
    bool isNumeric;
    float number;
    string numberInput;

    Console.Write("Enter Book Title: ");
    book.Title = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Author's First Name: ");
    book.AuthorFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Author's Last Name: ");
    book.AuthorLastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Book Price: $");
    numberInput = Console.ReadLine();

    isNumeric = float.TryParse(numberInput, out number);

    if (isNumeric)
        book.Price = number;
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException
        (
            "This is not a number!\n" +
            "Please try again."
        );  
    }
}
```

Whole Program.cs after edit which works. The problem was that ApplicationException part was displaying whole printout of the exception, now instead of doing that, it shows only message part. As usually it's something simple. :)

```
using System;

namespace Lab_6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Address address = new Address();
            address.StreetNumber = "800";
            address.StreetName = "East 96th Street";
            address.City = "Indianapolis";
            address.State = "IN";
            address.ZipCode = "46240";

            Book book = new Book();

            try
            {
                getBookInfo(book);
                book.PublisherAddress = address;
                book.PublisherName = "Sams Publishing"; 

                Console.WriteLine("----Book----");
                book.display();
            }
            catch (NegativeInputException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            catch (ApplicationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  // I had to change so I have only this, 
                                                // instead of whole printout.
                return;
            }
        }

        static void getBookInfo(Book book)
        {
            bool isNumeric;
            float number;
            string numberInput;

            Console.Write("Enter Book Title: ");
            book.Title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Author's First Name: ")
            book.AuthorFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Author's Last Name: ");
            book.AuthorLastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Book Price: $");
            numberInput = Console.ReadLine();

            isNumeric = float.TryParse(numberInput, out number);

            if (isNumeric)
                book.Price = number;
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException
                (
                    "This is not a number!\n" +
                    "Please try again."
                )   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason it does that, you could please fix the formatting.

Comment: This gave me a headache, but I have corrected it. Every time I paste code, then select, and press code formatting button it goes into double spacing... Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions don't show anything. That's up to the code that catches them.

Also, you should not use `ApplicationException`. Either use `Exception`, or use something more specific like `FormatException`.

Comment: But, what can I do to show only message description when non-number is entered? At this moment I'm being displayed the whole exception text. My instructions for this: When the book price is entered, you code should check to see if the entered value is a number. If yes, you can
assign the entered value to the Book object which is passed as the parameter. If not, you should throw an object of
ApplicationException.

Comment: First of all, your instructions don't say to just show the message, they say to throw an exception (tell your instructor to see [ApplicationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx) - wrong exception, shouldn't be used anymore). Second if you want to display the message, how about `Console.WriteLine("message");`?

Comment: That could be to simple. We are working on exception handling this week, so I figure this is out practice.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to show a message to user don't throw any exceptions just show the message.

```
if (isNumeric)
{
    book.Price = number;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is not a number!\n" + "Please try again.");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to throw an exception and show its message. Use Exception.Message to display.

```
try
{
    getBookInfo(...)
}
catch (ApplicationException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: No! OP want to throws an exception.

Comment: I could, but, I am specifically asked to throw an object of ApplicationException. Homework...

Comment: @HelpNeeder: What is your question?

Comment: The part I'm trying to work on is: "When the book price is entered, you code should check to see if the entered value is a number. If yes, you can
assign the entered value to the Book object which is passed as the parameter. If not, you should throw an object of
ApplicationException. Refer to the output of the sample runs." Sample run shows that is displayed only a message.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: In that case what you have done so far is correct. You have to call the getBookInfo method as I have shown in my edit in order to display the message to the user.

Comment: Look at my code in edit. I have done so already. So. When I have ApplicationException in Main, I should just call NegativeInputException again?

Comment: I just answered my own question :D Thank you for help.

Comment: @HelpNeeder:  cannot see new edit in your question. What you have done so far is correct. What you have to catch the exception when calling getBookInfo method as I have shown in my last edit. I am not too sure what is your problem...

Comment: If you throw an ApplicationException in the getBookInfo method you should catch the same exception type (ApplicationException) not NegativeInputException.

Comment: Well, what I had problem was that when I had an exception then the whole printout of inforamtion was showing. I have modified my second catch statement in main program to display all other exception to show "only" a message part. So I guess that is the reason why I can use ApplicationException itself.

Answer (score 2):

The act of throwing an Exception and the act of catching the exception and displaying the error to the user are two separate pieces.

Your code for throwing the exception when the entered value is not a float is correct.

What you need to do is surround your call to the static getBookInfo method with a try{} catch{} that catches the exception and displays the message

```
try
{
     Book myBookParameter = .....;
     getBookInfo(myBookParameter);
}
catch(ApplicationException x)
{
     MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
}
```